# How to find out if a cookie is already there?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

So I do simple JS function like

```
function writeCookie() 
{ 

var the_cookie = "users_resolution="+ screen.width +"x"+ screen.height; 

document.cookie=the_cookie 

}
```

how tm make sure that users_resolution is set?

Comment: in the current page or subsequent pages ?

Comment: in current page. but  subsequent pages are alsow point of intrest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a function like so:

```
  function getCookie(cName) {
    var cVal = document.cookie.match('(?:^|;) ?' + cName + '=([^;]*)(?:;|$)');
    if (!cVal) {
      return "";
    } else {
      return cVal[1];
    }
  }
```

Then, after you have set the cookie, you can call `getCookie()` and test it's return value, if it's equal to an empty string, or `""`, which is `false`, then the cookie doesn't exist. Otherwise you've got a valid cookie value.

The above paragraph in code:

```
var cookie = getCookie("users_resolution");
if (!cookie) {
   // cookie doesn't exist
} else {
  // cookie exists
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just do

```
var cookies = document.cookie;
```

then the string `cookies` will contain a semicolon-separated list of cookie name-value pairs.  You can split the string on `";"` and loop through the results, checking for the presence of your cookie name.

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't tag this as jQuery, but I made a [jQuery plugin to handle cookies](http://projects.zzzzbov.com/jquery-cookie-plugin/jquery.cookie.js), and this is the snippet that reads the cookie value:

```
  /**
   * RegExp Breakdown:
   * search from the beginning or last semicolon: (^|;)
   * skip variable number of spaces (escape backslash in string): \\s*
   * find the name of the cookie: name
   * skip spaces around equals sign: \\s*=\\s*
   * select all non-semicolon characters: ([^;]*)
   * select next semicolon or end of string: (;|$)
   */
  var regex = new RegExp( '(^|;)\\s*'+name+'\\s*=\\s*([^;]*)(;|$)' );
  var m = document.cookie.match( regex );
  // if there was a match, match[2] is the value
  // otherwise the cookie is null ?undefined?
  val =  m ? m[2] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `indexOf` to check whether it exists or not:

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf('users_resolution=') > 0){
  // cookie was set
}
```

Comment: What if there's a cookie with name `admin_users_resolution`?

Comment: This will not work if cookie starts with 'users_resolution'. As `indexOf` will get '0' if cookie starts with the same string you are looking for. So, please update your answer. Thanks.